# Want to remove a row from the tableview and delete the corresponding object from the array

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I want to delete one row from a tableview in Swift 5 and remove the object from the array. I searched a lot but couldn't get it done.

I tried all the related solutions available on StackOverflow but couldn't find it.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let position = indexPath.row
    if (editingStyle == .delete) {

        labDetailsTableView.beginUpdates()
        if let idx = labs.firstIndex(where: { $0 === position }) {
            labs.remove(at: idx)
        }


        labDetailsTableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

> Binary operator '===' cannot be applied to operands of type 'LabDetails' and 'Int'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `if let` block with just `labs.remove(at: position)`. No need for `firstIndex`.

You also do not need the calls to `beginUpdates` or `endUpdates`. But you do need to add a call to `tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == .delete) {
        let position = indexPath.row
        labs.remove(at: position)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}
```